# ReactJS functional component props issue inside useEffect in Hooks

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I'm using a functional component as a child with props from parent. In the props i have a `value`  array in which i'm getting as empty([]) inside useEffect and after some time, the same is getting rendered in the UI. I'm using useEffect to call a function and set the state only once as below and i want it to be like that. Here `value` is the props and `checkEmpty` is the function i'm checking and setting the state, `completed`. Is there any way to invoke the function inside useEffect once the `value` array is filled. But i want the useEffect to be invoked only once and needs to change the state `completed` with out letting it to an infinite loop.

```
 useEffect(() => {
        checkEmpty(value)?setCompleted(false):setCompleted(true)
      }, [])
```

Comment: Minor code refactor: `setCompleted( checkEmpty(value) );` You do not need a ternary operator

Answer (score 0):

You can pass  the `value` as a dependency of `useEffect`, and the hook only run when the `value` is changed.

```
useEffect(() => {
  checkEmpty(value) ? setCompleted(false) : setCompleted(true);
}, [value])
```

Comment: This could have been a comment, though it'll solve issue

Comment: Since the setComplete is a state change, this will result in an infinite loop right? The value is giving back to parent and setting to state in parent and passed as a props in our component.

Comment: Can you share the code of the parent and its child?